# Build GitPages Using GitHub Actions

Tags: build, github-actions, github-pages

> .github - workflows - github-pages.yml and dry-run.yml

---

```
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  github-pages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: helaili/jekyll-action@2.0.5
        build_only: true
Footer
```

---

```
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  github-pages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses:  helaili/jekyll-action@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Git Actions result
Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
Jekyll build done
Error: Cannot publish on branch master

master(Default branch) gh-pages(Active branches) I am using two branches.

What is the workaround for the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should change

```
on:
  push: 
    branches: 
      - master
```

to another branch

Comment: `on:  push: branches: - master`  -> `on:  push: branches: - git-pages`  change?